# How can I send formdata, objects, image?

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

Why can't I  send these two form values? In my POST data I have regular form data, a photo, and two objects "cat" and "medication"...

my post method....

```
  postCarelog(catID, catName) {
    axios.post(`/api/v1/carelogs/`, {
      cat: {id: catID, name: catName},
      weight_unit_measure: 'G',
      weight_before_food: this.weight_before_food,
      food_unit_measure: 'G',
      amount_of_food_taken: this.amount_of_food_taken,
      food_type: this.food_type,
      weight_after_food: this.weight_after_food,
      stimulated: this.stimulated,
      stimulation_type: this.stimulationType,
      medication: {name: this.medication,
        duration: '24',
        frequency: this.medication_dosage_given,
        dosage: this.dosage,
        notes: this.notes},
      medication_dosage_unit: 'ML',
      medication_dosage_given: this.medication_dosage_given,
      notes: this.notes,
      progress_photo: this.progress_photo.name,
    },{
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        response.status === 201 ? this.showSwal('success-message','Carelog added') : null;
        this.getFeedings(catName);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(catID, catName);
        console.log(error);
        this.showSwal('auto-close', error);
      })
  },
```

I get this error...

> {"cat":["This field is required."],"medication":["This field is required."]}

I have DRF on my backend and I have MultiPartParser set up in my api/views.py...(edited for brevity)

```
...
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser

...
class CareLogViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = CareLog.objects.all()
serializer_class = CareLogSerializer
parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
filter_fields = ('cat__slug', 'cat__name', 'food_type')
lookup_field = 'slug'
```

So why am I getting that error ?

UPDATE:

As requested, here is my template form...

```
<template>
               <form id="carelogAddForm">
                          <b-collapse id="collapseForm" class="mt-2">
                            <fg-input label="Create New Carelog"
                                      class="column-sizing">
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                  <b-form-select v-model="food_type" :options="foodOptions"></b-form-select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                  <b-input v-model="amount_of_food_taken" placeholder="Amount food taken"></b-input>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                  <b-form-input v-model="weight_before_food" placeholder="Weight Before Food"></b-form-input>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                  <b-input v-model="weight_after_food" placeholder="Weight After Food"></b-input>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                  <b-form-select v-model="stimulated" :options="stimulatedOps"></b-form-select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                  <b-form-select v-model="stimulationType" :options="stimulationTypeOps"></b-form-select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                  <b-form-select v-model="medication">
                                    <option selected :value="null">Medication</option>
                                    <option :value=catMed.name v-for="catMed in catMedications">{{catMed.name}}</option>
                                  </b-form-select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-2">
                                  <b-input v-model="medication_dosage_given" placeholder="Med. Dosage"></b-input>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <!--care photo upload-->
                                  <span v-if="window.width < 500">
                                    <input style="display: none" type="file" @change="onPhotoUpload" ref="fileInput2">
                                    <button id="progressImageBtn" class="btn" @click="$refs.fileInput2.click()">Upload Progress Image</button>
                                  </span>
                                  <span v-else>
                                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="file" @change="onPhotoUpload">
                                  </span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </fg-input>
                          </b-collapse>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info float-right" @click='showButton = !showButton' v-if="showButton" v-b-toggle.collapseForm>Add New Log</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning float-right ml-2" @click='showButton = !showButton' v-if="!showButton" v-b-toggle.collapseForm>Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success float-right" v-if="food_type !== 'MN' && !showButton"
                                      v-on:click="validateSubmitNoMom(scope.item.id, scope.item.name, scope.item.slug)" @click='showButton = !showButton'>Submit</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success float-right" v-if="food_type === 'MN' && !showButton"
                                      v-on:click="validateSubmitMom(scope.item.id, scope.item.name)">Submit mom</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </form>
</template>
```

And my Data Object (fair warning it is long...their is much more going on in the app in general)

```
data () {
  return {
    medication: null,
    modals: {
      basic: false,
      centered: false,
      custom: false,
      confirm: false
    },
    onFiltered: '',
    variableAtParent: 'DATA FROM PARENT!',
    activeName: 'first',
    currentSort:'name',
    currentSortDir:'asc',
    collapsed: true,
    medToEdit: [],
    feedToEdit: [],
    page: 1,
    CatIndex: 0,
    pagination: {
      perPage: 5,
      currentPage: 1,
      perPageOptions: [5, 10, 25, 50],
      total: 0
    },
    sortBy: null,
    sortDesc: false,
    sortDirection: 'asc',
    filter: null,
    searchQuery: '',
    propsToSearch: ['name', 'gender', 'age', 'id', 'birthday', 'catType'],
    cat: '',
    cat_type: '',
    example1: [],
    cats: [],
    thisCat: [],
    catFeedings: [],
    catMedications: [],
    careLogTableColumns: [],
    careLogColumns: [
      'id',
      'progressPhoto',
      'foodType',
      'amountOfFoodTaken',
      'stimulated',
      'weightBeforeFood',
      'weightAfterFood',
      'stimulationType',
      'medication',
      'medicationDosageGiven',
      'actions',
    ],
    tableColumns: [
      {
        key: 'id',
        prop: 'id',
        label: 'ID',
        minWidth: 90
      },
      {
        key: 'photo',
        prop: 'photo',
        label: 'Photo',
        minWidth: 100
      },
      {
        key: 'name',
        prop: 'name',
        label: 'Name',
        minWidth: 100,
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'gender',
        prop: 'gender',
        label: 'Sex',
        minWidth: 50,
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'birthday',
        prop: 'birthday',
        label: 'Birthdate',
        minWidth: 140,
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'age',
        prop: 'birthday',
        label: 'Age',
        minWidth: 100,
        sortable: false
      },
      {
        key: 'catType',
        prop: 'catType',
        label: 'Type',
        minWidth: 60,
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'actions',
        prop: 'actions',
        label: 'Actions',
        minWidth: 60
      },
    ],
    fuseSearch: null,
    weight_before_food: '',
    weight_after_food: '',
    amount_of_food_taken: '',
    food_type: null,
    foodOptions:[
      { value: null, text: 'Food Type' },
      { value: 'MN', text: 'Mom (Nursing)' },
      { value: 'BO', text: 'Bottle' },
      { value: 'BS', text: 'Bottle/Syringe' },
      { value: 'SG', text: 'Syringe Gruel'},
      { value: 'GG', text: 'Syringe Gruel / Gruel'},
      { value: 'G', text: 'Gruel'},
    ],
    notes:    '',
    stimulated: null,
    stimulatedOps: [
      { value: null, text: 'Stimulated' },
      'true',
      'false'
    ],
    stimulationType: null,
    stimulationTypeOps: [
      { value: null, text: 'Stim. Type' },
      { value: 'UR', text: 'Urine'},
      { value: 'FE', text: 'feces'},
      { value: 'UF', text: 'Urine / Feces'},
    ],
    showSuccess: false,
    showDanger: false,
    constant: 0,
    dismissSecs: 4,
    dismissCountDown: 0,
    dismissCountDown2: 0,
    nursing: false,
    handleAdd: true,
    showRow: true,
    showButton: true,
    showButton2: true,
    dosage_unit: 'ML',
    dosage:    '',
    dosageGuidelines: '',
    weightBeforeFood: '',
    amountOfFoodTaken: '',
    foodType: '',
    duration: '',
    frequency: '',
    name:   '',
    medication_dosage_given: '',
    progress_photo: null,
    window: {
      width: 0,
      height: 0
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: could you provide your data object and the template

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim I don't know if that is going to help at all. if what you want to know if just what are the contents of "cat" and "medication"? But I've included the entire data object as requested.

Comment: Why my code chunks here always have auto highlight? ))

Comment: @Jessi why do you do `<option :value=catMed.name v-for="catMed in catMedications">{{catMed.name}}</option>` ? i recommend to use `:value="catMed"`